# DataBinding help in Flex 4

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, flex4, flash-builder

I managed to make the enabled thing work.

```
<s:Button x="388" y="219" width="180" height="40"
          label="Generate Code" fontWeight="bold"
          enabled="{(mbUniqueID.text!='')}" />
```

But I'm having trouble adding two dependencies to the button being enabled. How do I make this button enabled **only if** *mbUniqueID.text* **and** *mbWinContent.text* is not empty. I want to do this via DataBinding. I can do it without any problems via AS3 but I wanted that approach. I have successfully made the *mbUniqueID.text* DataBinding work. I just need to know how to make it dependent on two factors instead of just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
   <s:Button x="388" y="219" width="180" height="40"
      label="Generate Code" fontWeight="bold"
      enabled="{mbUniqueID.text !='' ? mbWinContent.text != '' ? true : false : false  }"
     />
```

It is not the best example but it will work.

How it works ([ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a)):

```
variable = condition ? value if true : value if false
```

Comment: Can you explain the above example? I mean I don't quite get what the "?" operator is for? And also I tried mbUniqueID.text!='' && mbWinContent.text!='' but it failed.

Comment: I can't seem to comprehend how it works right now but anyway, it did the trick so thank you!